# Start function after another is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have a javascript file and there are a two function all_surveys() and survey(). Both function are API calls. I want to start function all_surveys() at the beginning and when it is done I want to start function survey(). How can I do this?

```
function all_surveys(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url_surveys,
    dataType: "json",
    success :
      function (data) {
      //some code
    },
    error:
});
}

function survey(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url_survey,
    dataType: "json",
    success :
      function (data) {
      //some code
    },
    error:
});
}
```

Comment: Call the 2nd function inside the `success` callback from the first function.

Comment: `success: survey` maybe?

Comment: Call it inside `success`.

Comment: Just leaving a nice intro into deferreds in jquery: http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/

Comment: One call doesn't seem to rely on the other, so why wait ?

Comment: @adeneo: one call to rule them all

Comment: @zerkms - That returns my "precious" instead of a "promise" ?

Answer (score 3):

Use promises!

```
function all_surveys() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url_surveys,
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function (data) {
        //some code
        return …;
    });
}

function survey() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url_survey,
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function (data) {
        //some code
        return …;
    });
}

all_surveys().then(function(allsurveysResult) {
    surveys();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
all_surveys();
function all_surveys(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url_surveys,
    dataType: "json",
    success: survey,
});
}

function survey(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url_survey,
    dataType: "json",
    success :
      function (data) {
      //some code
    },
});
}
```

If you want to do stuff with the data or do more than one thing, you'll have to use an anonymous function, though:

```
all_surveys();
function all_surveys(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url_surveys,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){survey(); /* console.log(data) */},
});
}

function survey(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url_survey,
    dataType: "json",
    success :
      function (data) {
      //some code
    },
});
}
```

Comment: How about just `success: survey`?

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks, I never actually did it that way.  I'm used to anonymous functions.

Comment: You have just reached the next level, treating functions as first-class values, just like a string or array. :)

Comment: @Phrogz Unless you want to do more than one thing or use the data

Comment: @Doorknob: the data will be passed actually

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, removed.